# show database in datagridview without header

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, datagridview

i want to load database table to datagridview to i can edit and update the column , I'm now using list view but i want to use gartagridview because its more ease to edit the data in it .

I'm using this code to show data in database in list view :

```
Public Sub showlistview()
    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from pay_pretalk where cust_id=" & pretalk_pay.TextBox4.Text & " order by sdate DESC ", con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim myrow As DataRow
        For Each myrow In dt.Rows
            ListView1.Items.Add(myrow.Item(0))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(2))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(3))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(4))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(5))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(6))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(7))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

how can i do the same in datagridview without showing the header of the database and use my custom header in the datagridview properties.

if i use this code to show data in datagridview :

```
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from pay_pretalk where cust_id=" & pretalk_pay.TextBox4.Text & " order by sdate DESC ", con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

this show all table with the header !, but i have already add a custom header , so this miss up everything :(

Comment: Do you mean without showing the column names in the header of each column of a datagridview?

Comment: yes @Steve i want to add just the records from database , i want the header column  in deferent names .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the DataGridView.DataSource property with the datatable retrieved you could start a simple loop that changes the columns header text to your preferences

```
.....
dt.Columns.RemoveAt(1)
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt

for each cl As DataGridViewColumn in dataGridView1.Columns
    Select Case cl.HeaderText
        Case "FirstColumnName": 
           cl.HeaderText="MyColumn1Name" 
        Case "SecondColumnName": 
           cl.HeaderText="MyColumn2Name"
        case "ThirdColumnName": 
            cl.HeaderText="MyColumn3Name"

        ... and so on for the other columns ....
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: is there way to add data in the grid view like list view ??

Comment: Do you mean without showing the column at index 1? Yes just call dt.Columns.RemoveAt(1) before binding the table to your grid

Comment: simply what i have is a data grid view with header i add from properties 
what i want just get the data from database and add it in the datagridview

Comment: The DataGridView sets the columns header with the names of the columns from your database. So, supposing that your table has 3 columns named Col1, Col2, Col3, then change them to ID, Name, Phone within the loop shown above

Comment: its work thanks 
but still what i need better than this solution , because i can change the header properties and so on 
but thanks you are great :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set to `false` the [auto generate columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the datagridview, and use the [data property name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname(v=vs.110).aspx) property of each column to map it to a column of the data source.

Sample Code:

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
Dim index As Integer
index = DataGridView1.Columns.Add("ColumnA", "ColumnA")
DataGridView1.Columns(index).DataPropertyName = "Column1"
index = DataGridView1.Columns.Add("ColumnB", "ColumnB")
DataGridView1.Columns(index).DataPropertyName = "Column2"
index = DataGridView1.Columns.Add("ColumnC", "ColumnC")
DataGridView1.Columns(index).DataPropertyName = "Column3"

Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dt)
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5 FROM Table1 WHERE Condition = true", con)
da.Fill(dt)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

This way you're selecting `Column1` to `Column5` from the table but only `Column1` to `Column3` will appear on the DGV; also the column headers will be `ColumnA`, `ColumnB` and `ColumnC`.

You can also specify this in design-time on the DataGridView, to save some code and to define from the very beggining wich columns will appear and how; you'll only need to set `AutoGenerateColumns = false` before setting it's data source.

[image: DataPropertyName in design]